# Would a quantum computer solve the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: open-problem, quantum-computation

I heard that a quantum computer can give many results as one computation step. Does it mean that it would be just a brute force search for a quantum computer to solve for example the Riemann's hypothesis or Goldbach's conjecture?

Comment: I get the feeling it would not be a matter of brute force since the hypothesis is about an infinite sum happening at uncountably many points.

Comment: Quantum computers, as far as I know, don't get around the $\mathsf P = \mathsf {NP}$ problem, but that's not even the problem here. Both conjectures you name concern infinite sets, so brute force is not an option, and in the case of the Riemann Hypothesis even less so because I don't think we can exactly evaluate the zeta function (again this is moot because the domain of $\zeta$ is infinite). Unless you mean brute force over logical symbols and such, in which case the sun will probably die first.

Comment: @JoeMoeller all proofs in math can in principle be formalized in the language of set theory, and in particular, are finite. Of course, you can also confirm this by observing that you've never seen an infinite proof, formal or not. The point being that if you had to check uncountably many points separately, it would be impossible to prove RH regardless of whether you had a quantum computer-or most varieties of magic wand.

Comment: @GPerez P versus NP is not totally irrelevant here: assuming we are indeed talking about proofs in first-order logic, then it's hard to find a proof but easy to check it's right, which is the same way P-NP feels. But it's true both that if q-computers could solve P vs NP that wouldn't give us any guarantees about first-order logic, which is undecidable so certainly not in NP, and that quantum computers are not known or, for the most part, suspected to be able to solve NP problems in polynomial time.

Comment: Right, which is why brute force is generally not the preferred method for infinite cases. If you can classify the problem into finitely many, but still too many for a human, then a quantum computer would probably be useful. But as far as I'm aware, this hasn't been done yet.

Comment: @JoeMoeller it's not true than quantum computers can help with any old parallel problem. There is a handful of very specialized algorithms that are better than the best classical approximations.

Comment: @JoeMoeller If the statement is provably true, then (tautologically) there exists a proof of it in formal logic containing a finite number of symbols. Similarly, if the statement is provably false then there exists a proof of its negation containing a finite number of symbols. Infinity issues would only arise if the statement is true but unprovable, such as in Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @KevinCarlson It does seem related now (and given the latest answer it turns out even more so). What I wanted to get across was that if we consider that we have an "instance of a problem": `find where the zeros of this function are`, with the (infinite) domain of the function as the "input space" then P-NP has no bearing, withholding for the moment the meta-realization that we are dealing with strings of characters. I don't know it this "anti-abstraction" can be formalized, but I hope that what I mean is clear.

Comment: NO.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user3491648 Have you looked at the answers? It's not strictly impossible, just very very,.........,very, very unlikely. So unlikely that it makes more sense to *consider* it impossible. But perhaps you mean this.

Comment: @GPerez to formalize it computationally you might talk about machines that compute directly with complex numbers, which don't exist physically but have been studied by Blum-Smale-Shub.

Comment: Brute forcing all strings of characters to find a proof is probably not what the question was referring to. My point is that it's probably going to require something clever, not just performing a lot of calculations, in the way the four color theorem was proved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's already possible in principle to prove theorems via brute force, because it's relatively easy to check whether some random string of digits is a proof of the Riemann hypothesis. The problem is that this is too slow to finish in the next $10^{100}$ years or so. The problems that quantum computation can speed up are thus far few and very special, so there's no reason whatsoever to expect that a quantum computer would help with this, although it's not impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Since automated theorem proving is in NP, this question can be rephrased as follows:

> Does the complexity class [BQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=BQP) contain [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29)?

The answer is currently **unknown**, but it is suspected not to be true. Here is a discussion on MO:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35151/what-impact-would-p-np-have-on-the-characterization-of-bqp

See also, related discussion on TCS:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/if-p-np-could-we-obtain-proofs-of-goldbachs-conjecture-etc